# Display all the values of each category per date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating report from temporary table to generate data per date with each category 
Here's the example data and table

```
| Category  | Percentage   | Date       |
| Assets    | 12.89        | 2020-01-31 |
| Revenue   | 34.78        | 2020-01-31 |
| Expenses  | 30.88        | 2020-01-31 |
```

and here's the mysql query I tried

```
Select Date,
(CASE WHEN Category='Assets' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS asset,
(CASE WHEN Category='Revenue' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS income,
(CASE WHEN Category='Expenses' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS expense
from tbl_temporary1 WHERE Date='2020-01-31'
```

Instead of one row result, it become something like this

```
| Date       | asset  | income  | expense  |
| 2020-01-31 | 12.89  | 0.00    | 0.00     |
| 2020-01-31 | 0.00   | 34.78   | 0.00     |
| 2020-01-31 | 0.00   | 0.00    | 30.88    |
```

Result Expected

```
| Date       | asset  | income  | expense  |
| 2020-01-31 | 12.89  | 34.78   | 30.88    |
```

Hope you could help me to fix, I tried to join the table by itself but same results.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(no subquery is needed here)

You almost had it right.  Add sums and group by:

```
Select Date,
SUM(CASE WHEN Category='Assets' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS asset,
SUM(CASE WHEN Category='Revenue' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS income,
SUM(CASE WHEN Category='Expenses' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS expense
from tbl_temporary1
WHERE Date='2020-01-31'
GROUP BY Date
```

If only one date is selected, the GROUP BY can be omitted, since the use of an aggregate function (SUM) makes it default to grouping all rows together.

Comment: yes, it is simple...why this didn't come to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query and let me know if you face any issue.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(asset)asset, SUM(income)income, SUM(expense) FROM
(
Select Date,
(CASE WHEN Category='Assets' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS asset,
(CASE WHEN Category='Revenue' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS income,
(CASE WHEN Category='Expenses' THEN Percentage ELSE 0 END) AS expense
from tbl_temporary1 WHERE Date='2020-01-31')temp
GROUP BY Date
```